# Coalesce FETCHING 0 ROWS inside stored procedure but fetches result as a query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Sample data

```
srNO  productname StartDate    AStartdate       pStartdate
1       new       11-11-2010    11-11-2010      11-11-2010
2       old       01-01-2011    11-11-2011      09-11-2010
3       medium    01-01-2012    01-01-2012      16-07-2012
4       out       01-08-2012    16-01-2012      16-07-2012
```

my query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Status_yearly]
(@MID NVARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Years nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Years = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' 
                                       + Cast(Year(u.StartDate) AS 
                                       NVARCHAR(4 
                                              )) 
                                       + ']' 
                       FROM   [products] u 
                       FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') 
DECLARE @date nvarchar(max)
SET @date =CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105)
-- SELECT @date
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = '
select
    *
from (
    select
      ''Product'' AS Status,''total_product'' as [YEAR], 
      productname, year(u.StartDate) as [y]
    from products u  WHERE 
    MID ='''+@MID+''' 
    AND u.Flag <> 0 

  ) Data
PIVOT (
  COUNT(productname)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    ' + @Years + '
  )
) PivotTable

UNION ALL 
select
    *
from (
    select ''Finished'' AS Finished,
      ''In Time'' as [YEAR], 
     Coalesce(COUNT(productsname),0) AS productsname, Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.StartDate)),0) as [y]
    from products u  WHERE  u.AStartdate IS NOT NULL 
    AND u.AStartdate = u.pStartdate
    AND MID ='''+@MID+''' 


  ) Data
PIVOT (
  COUNT(productsname)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    ' + @Years + '
  )
) PivotTable

'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
END
```

This gives me the result

```
    Status     Year            2012
    Product   total_product     4
    FINISHED  In Time           0
```

```
 select ''Finished'' AS Finished,
      ''In Time'' as [YEAR], 
     Coalesce(COUNT(productsname),0) AS productname, Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.StartDate)),0) as [y]
    from products u  WHERE  u.AStartdate IS NOT NULL 
    AND u.AStartdate = u.pStartdate
    AND MID ='''+@MID+'''
```

This is giving me result like

```
Finished   YEAR     productname  Y
FINISHED  In Time        1       1
```

Individually it gives me count as 1 but when executed inside stored procedure it give me 0.

SO how do I implement this inside the procedure? Please note some time there may not be any result set in the 'finished' block that is why I am using

```
Coalesce(COUNT(productsname),0) AS productname, Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.StartDate)),0)
```

please suggest..

Database is SQL Server

Comment: PRINT @SQL and see what it returns

Comment: no it does not. Some logic is missing not able to figure out what?

Comment: @Mdharmendra, please post the schema of your table as well as some sample data ... You could use http://www.sqlfiddle.com and post the link with the schema/data

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that your sample data is missing the `flag` and `mid` column (*i assume it is there in your table*), the problem seems to be a wrong column name used.

`COUNT(productsname)` should be `COUNT(productname)` (removed the ***s***).

Comment: I know that, that's not the problem.